# I am using a recursive function and need to print from within the function just once

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, printf

I am using python 3 and need to print the final result from within the function(this is not optional). Instead it is printing every time it goes through the function.

```
def reverseDisplay(number):
#base case 
#if number is only one digit, return number

  if number<10:
        return number 
  else:
        result = int(str(number%10) + str(reverseDisplay(number//10)))


  print(result)
  return(result)

def main():
     number = int(input("Enter a number: "))
     reverseDisplay(number)

main()
```

If you enter `12345` it prints out

```
21

321

4321

54321
```

I want it to print out `54321`

Comment: How about just a `print reverseDisplay(number)` in your `main()`? (removing the `print` within the `reverseDisplay` function itself`?

Comment: The print function needs to be part of the function. I know it's silly, but it's a school assignment and I need to follow the instructions exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following worked for me (after I found a Python 3 interpreter online):

```
def reverseDisplay(n):
    tmp = n % 10       # Determine the rightmost digit,
    print(tmp, end="") #  and print it with no space or newline.
    if n == tmp:       # If the current n and the rightmost digit are the same...
        print()        #    we can finally print the newline and stop recursing.
    else:              # Otherwise...
        reverseDisplay(n // 10)  # lop off the rightmost digit and recurse.
```

If you need to return the reversed value in addition to printing it:

```
def reverseDisplay(n):
    tmp = n % 10
    print(tmp, end="")
    if n == tmp:
        print()
        return tmp
    else:
        return int(str(tmp) + str(reverseDisplay(n // 10)))
```

Comment: I just used the first part without returning the value.

Comment: @KiraShelton I added comments that should clear things up.  Let me know if there's still stuff that's unclear.

Comment: To me, this does not constitute 'print the final result' as I would imagined intended by the instructor.  To be at all sensible as a teaching device, 'print the final result' would be a proxy for 'do something with the final result. I would submit Le Petit Prince's solution instead.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy - When you call the function the result gets printed from within the function before it hands control back to you, and doesn't have any additional arguments (which _could_ be abused by end users).  I think it meets the requirements just fine. If the signature of the function was `reverse(number, display=True)`, I'd agree.

Comment: @Terry Jan Reedy This answer actually helps a lot because my prof had given us info about the end parameter in print and I had no idea why I would need to use it. Also I'm not allowed to insert any more parameters into the reverseDisplay function or use any other functions.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to move your `print` statement out of the `reverseDisplay` and into `main`:

```
def reverseDisplay(number):
#base case 
#if number is only one digit, return number

  if number<10:
        return number 
  else:
        result = int(str(number%10) + str(reverseDisplay(number//10)))
  return result

def main():
    number = 12345
    print reverseDisplay(number)

main()
```

Comment: OP says he has to have the print function within the recursive function itself.

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to print it in the recursive function, you'll have to add a parameter (called `first` in this example) to make sure you only print the first time:

```
def reverseDisplay(number, first=True):
    if number<10:
        return number 
    else:
        result = int(str(number%10) + str(reverseDisplay(number//10, False)))
        if first:
            print(result)
        return result
```

Comment: My guess is that a `first` parameter is the solution intended by the instructor.  It does not depend on processing the result before the final return being a print than can be simulated a digit at a time.  But I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def reverseDisplayPrinter(number):
    print reverseDisplay(number)

def reverseDisplay(number):
    if number<10:
        return number 
    else:
        result = int(str(number%10) + str(reverseDisplay(number//10)))

    return(result)

def main():
    number = int(input("Enter a number: "))
    reverseDisplayPrinter(number)

main()
```

Comment: This gives me an error message that say "invalid literal for int() with base 10: 2None

Comment: I don't have any error here, @KiraShelton. It's working fine.